# Text Box Background Color

Tags: html, css, header

I've changed the color of my header, which includes a logo and a title.

In the title, the text box where the words appear are taking the `background-color` of the background of the body of the website, and not taking the background color of the header.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

.headerMenu {
  background-color: #00b9ED;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.logo {
  width: 125px;
}

.logo img {
  background-color: #00b9ED;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 38px;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
}

.headerTitle {
  background-color: #00b9ED;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 80PX;
  font-family: 'oswald', arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <title>FINDPETS</title>
  <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</HEAD>

<body>
  <div class="headerMenu">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="headerTitle">
        <h2>PET FRIENDS</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="./IMG/dog_bone_logo.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</HTML>
```

Photo of the resulting error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the asterisk selector `*` is called the [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) . Which means it selects all elements so it will add all those properties ( including background-color ) to the `title` as well.

You can just remove the background-color property rule from  `* {}` and add it to a new `body {}` selector. That way the background-color property won't be applied to all your elements but only to body

```css
body {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

* {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.headerMenu {
  background-color: #00b9ED;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.logo {
  width: 125px;

}

.logo img {
  background-color: #00b9ED;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 38px;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;


}

.headerTitle {
  background-color: #00b9ED;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 80PX;
  font-family: 'oswald', arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerMenu">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="headerTitle">
      <h2>PET FRIENDS</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="./IMG/dog_bone_logo.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```